# UDF using Groovy to filter nodes

Tags: groovy, user-defined-functions

I am trying to filter description nodes from the below xml basing on the language in graphical mapping.

```
<Root>
  <Parent>
    <Lang>EN</Lang>
    <desc>hello</desc>
  </Parent>
   <Parent>
     <Lang>DE</Lang>
    <desc>gutentag</desc>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
     <Lang>EN</Lang>
     <desc>Good morning</desc>
    </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <Lang>EN</Lang>
      <desc>Hellothere</desc>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
      <Lang>DE</Lang>
      <desc>Guten Morg</desc>
     </Parent>
</Root>
```

I tried the below code for UDF but its throwing null values.

```
import com.sap.it.api.mapping.*;

def String customFunc(String arg1,String arg2){
    if(arg1 =="EN"){def result = arg2
    return result
}}
```

Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong and what needs to be changed in the code?
this is how we need to get XML

```
<RootNode>
   <Values>
      <Value>hello</Value>
       <Value>Good morning</Value>
       <Value>Hellothere</Value>
   </Values>
</RootNode>
```